# Robot Framework - Expected Failure after Prod Refresh

Tags: validation, robotframework, testcase

One of my automated test cases (TC) fails predictably after a prod refresh that takes place every few months. 
For the TC to pass, there should be 'N/A' for values, which is a precondition. After getting the 'N/A' text, I do insert into a table to create values and then do other steps.
After the refresh, there are values (monies) instead of the 'N/A'. 
What are the ways to avoid the failure? Run Keyword If and Run Keyword And Expect Failure would invalidate the original TC and and it will always pass, which I apparently don't need.

Answer (score 1):

There might be other approaches too, however, one of the ways to approach this problem is

1. You can define [init](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files) file in directory

```
    __init__.robot
```

That suite setup and suite teardown in the file would run before anything in the underlying folders.

2. **make use of [set global variable](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable)** with N/A and update the same when you see actual values. i.e every test case would verify whether the variable contains N/A or actual values(i.e not N/A), this can be done using Test Setup with keyword.

**NOTE: You can also use [set suite variable](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) for the same**

Comment: please accept the answer, if it has provided solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers